# Using React boilerplate, and localhost gives error: Uncaught ReferenceError: text is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm adding my own code to `React` boilerplate, but it stops working when I added getInitialState function, complains about error in return:

```
var React = require('react');

var App = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function(){
    return(
            text: ""
    );
  },


    updateText: function(txt){
    this.setState({
      text: txt.target.value
    });
  },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <h1>Hello world!</h1>
        );
    }

});

module.exports = App;
```

Comment: Did you mean to return a dictionary rather than what I assume is a syntax error?

Comment: maybe change `text:""` to `{text:""}`

Comment: In `getInitialState()` you should be returning an object, which uses curly braces `{}` not parentheses `()`. `(text:"")` is not valid Javascript or JSX, whereas `{text:""}` would be.

Comment: Thank you! How come you return object inside curly braces inside getInitialState, but not in another return statements?

Comment: getInitialState always returns an object of the state properties you setting. You could just do `this.state({text: ""})` this in the constructor if that is easier to understand. They are equivalent.